# What is the source code for norm_rand() which is called in rnorm() function in R?

Tags: r

I would like to know the source code for rnorm() function. Hence, I looked for it in the web and found the github page https://github.com/wch/r-source/find/trunk where I could see the source code which is

```
#include "nmath.h"

double rnorm(double mu, double sigma)
{
    if (ISNAN(mu) || !R_FINITE(sigma) || sigma < 0.)
    ML_ERR_return_NAN;
    if (sigma == 0. || !R_FINITE(mu))
    return mu; /* includes mu = +/- Inf with finite sigma */
    else
    return mu + sigma * norm_rand();
}
```

Here, it calls norm_rand() function. I am not able to find its source code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `norm_rand` is used to generate random numbers. Please look [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/snorm.c#L62).

  Voting to close for *seeking recommendations for off-site resources*

Comment: @PoGibas, I think this question isn't asking for recommendations, it's asking for specific information, so it's fine.  It's not "likely to lead to opinion-based answers", other than opinions like the one I posted in my answer about the reliability of a mirror.

Comment: @user2554330 It's asking for a off-site resource (library, book, source-code).

Comment: @PoGibas:  yes, but read the full description:  "It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."  The second sentence doesn't apply to this question.  It's not looking for opinions, it's looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the source on Github, you can usually find the source to functions just by searching for the text.  For example, if you search for `norm_rand` within the https://github.com/wch/r-source/ repository, the first two hits are functions calling `norm_rand`, but the third one is the function definition, with this link:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/snorm.c#L62

That repository isn't the official one for R sources, but it does seem to reliably mirror it.  The current official version of that file is at

https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/snorm.c

but I don't think svn.r-project.org offers as easy a way to search as Github does.